# 'run-s' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, npm

I surprisingly got that issue out of nowhere, when I was trying to use the `npm link` command testing my local package. Any thoughts?

Windows 10
node 15.9.0
npm 8.12.2

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the issue was because my npm version didn't match my node version.

I was trying to install that 'run-s' package globally but it didn't help. I checked my environment variables but it didn't help either.

After all I just simply uninstalled nodejs, deleted all the files that it left and installed the needed version again (12.22.12 in my case) using "windows-nvm" and now everything runs smoothly.

Now my NodeJS version is 12.22.12
my NPM version is 6.14.16

Hope it will help somebody

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
npm install npm-run-all --save-dev
```

The [link](https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all#readme) is here.